# How can I use the shell to make my mp3s a Shoutcast source?

Tags: linux, streaming, audio

I'm looking to stream a directory of mp3s from my audio source (Debian server) to my Shoutcast server. The idea is to have an archive playing in the instance that someone isn't broadcasting live.

I'm not sure how to continue. I started with extensive Google-ing, and was unable to come up with a solution. Evan Carroll suggested I try here.

I appreciate any insight y'all may have.

---

On a side note, "users with less than 100 reputation can't create new tags. The tags 'shoutcast-source shoutcast broadcasting' are new. Try using existing tags instead." -- Who can create these?

Answer (score 1):

I use the sc_trans utility along with sc_serv. You run both of them from the command line.

like this:

```
./sc_serv myserv.conf &
./sc_trans mytrans.conf &
```

If you google for sc_trans you get a bunch of links, mostly at shoutcast.com, that show how to set up sc_trans and its config file and a playlist of the mp3 files you want to stream...

Hope this helps.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be a bit heavier than what you want, you can stream to a Shoutcast server [using MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Configuration#IceCast).  I haven't done that myself (only used the builtin http streaming), but what I've done with it has been fairly simple to configure.